# JavaScript: Should one check for undefined before calling every function that is defined in other JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Should one check for `undefined` before accessing any function of other JavaScript? Let's suppose we have included utils.js in our HTML page and it has the following main.js that calls `getqs` function of utils.js like:

```
if (typeof utils !== "undefined")
{
   utils.getqs();
}
```

Though we have included utils.js at the top in deferred sequence in the HTML page so it's guaranteed to load before the main.js, should we check if utils.js has loaded or failed by checking `typeof utils !== "undefined"` before calling any of its functions?

One advantage of checking this is that if we start using this main.js anywhere else where we are not using utils, it would work fine, BUT on the other side, too many such checks might slow down the performance and increase the size of the JavaScript file.

Comment: Should be `!== "undefined"` and `typeof` isn't a function so the parentheses are redundant

Comment: yeah.. changed it.

Comment: As you said, you loaded the script in a guaranteed way, so it's there, so just use it. That way if you get an error, you know something is wrong and can fix it. Using `typeof` like this is easy to get wrong, like you have in the question, and so just leads to further confusion and bugs.

Comment: You've started with *"Though we have included utils.js... so its guaranteed...*"  but then transition to *"if we start using this main.js anywhere else where we are not using utils..."* So on one hand your question is based on a reliable situation, but on the other hand, it's asking about a different, unreliable situation. Which one are you actually wondering about? What are the ramifications of it being absent? Is `utils` an integral part of the script? Sometimes a script *should* break if an important dependency is not met.

Comment: ...well anyway, if I assume that the *behavior* of `utils` is unimportant to the proper functioning of the page, but an error due to its absence would be catastrophic, then I'd check for its existence once, and define a noop in its place. `if (!window.utils) window.utils = {getqs:function(){}};` But I don't know what the benefit is of a sometimes-necessary dependency.

Answer (score 2):

No, if the module was included you should be able to expect that `utils` is available.

As you said, "*we have included utils.js at the top in deferred sequencce in the html page so its guaranteed to load before the main.js*". It's not actually guaranteed, as the inclusion might fail (e.g. a 404 for the script file), but this would cause an error. An an exception when trying to access methods on undefined `utils`.

Testing whether `utils` exists only makes sense when you can *handle* the case that it doesn't. Your code doesn't have an `else`. You might want to test for existence and load a fallback script, or alert the user, or redirect to an error page, or at least send a log message home to the server for monitoring.

So **no**, it doesn't make any sense to check the existence of every function before every individual call.

Comment: but there's just one problem that if we don't place this safety check and now main.js is used on some other html page where we don't have utils.js included, that page would break.

Comment: @maverick What's the difference between "*break*" and "*does not do `getqs()`*"?

Comment: "break" here would make page non-responsive while even if doesn't go to getqs(), one feature on the page would not be shown

Comment: @maverick Well if "do not show the feature" is how you want to handle it here, then go for it. But you cannot make arbitrary functions just do nothing without an error.

Answer (score -2):

If you really want to than use [try / catch](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp) statement:

```js
try {
   utils.getqs();
   function2();
   function3();
} catch (error) {
   console.log ('Error occured', error);
}
```

In this case you don;t have to check existance of every function seperatelly, but normally you wouldn't do that kind of checks.

Comment: Why is this better than `typeof`?

Comment: Because in this case he doesn't have to check every function call seperatelly.

Answer (score -3):

It depends on the way you implement your Js. Usually, you don't have to do that. In some cases it does, but then you have to catch it.

Comment: This answer is factually correct, but if you don't state *what* it depends on then its quite useless.